# Append results from a shell command to a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a shell command inside Python to collect the IPv4 address in a server.

```
# cat ipv4.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
ipv4_regex = r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
os_cmd = f"ip a s eth0 | egrep -o 'inet {ipv4_regex}' | cut -d' ' -f2"
os.system(os_cmd)
```

Output:

```
# ./ipv4.py
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
```

How do I append each IPv4 address from the above output to a list in Python?.

Comment: You *can't* do that with `os.system()` - the output from the command went directly to your terminal, Python never saw it.  You will need to use one of the functions in the `subprocess` module - `.run()` perhaps.

Comment: @jasonharper `subprocess.check_output()`, more specifically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the return of the *os.system()* method you are invocating is not directly what you are expecting.
Instead, try using *os.popen()*, it is the same, essentialy, as the subprocess check_output() method:

```
import os
ipv4_regex = r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
os_cmd = f"ip a s eth0 | egrep -o 'inet {ipv4_regex}' | cut -d' ' -f2"
x = os.popen(os_cmd).read()
```

Afterwards you can do some treatment in order get the return in the desired structure, creating a list from each line of *x* as example:

```
ips_list = x.split('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll need the `subprocess` module to capture output from a process.
2. You'll probably have a better time finding your matches in Python rather than build a shell pipeline.

```
import re
import subprocess
import shlex

match_re = re.compile(
    r"inet ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})"
)


def get_ips(interface_name):
    ips = match_re.findall(
        subprocess.check_output(
            f"ip a s {shlex.quote(interface_name)}",
            shell=True,
            encoding="utf-8",
        )
    )
    return ips


print(get_ips("eno1"))
```

This directly prints out (e.g.)

```
['192.168.1.20']
```

since `findall()` gets you the first capture group from the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output(['os_cmd'])
```